# How to translate such PHP code using CURL into C/C++?

Tags: php, c++, c, openid, libcurl

I decided to implement OpenID login into my C++ server. I looked at list of avaliable C++ OpenID clients and found only one popular [`libopkele`](http://kin.klever.net/libopkele/requirements). But its requirements seem quite way 2 much for my simple server which has its own xml parser, uses boost for regexps and so on.

So I want to create simple openID client in C++, so I decided to port PHPclient (because I know PHPa bit). There is class called [`class.openid.php`](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3290-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-OpenID-single-sign-on.html) which in its first version is just 200 lines of PHP code. My main problem is I never used curl before in PHP nor in c++. SO I beg for help in translating to C/C++ such PHP code:

```
function CURL_Request($url, $method="GET", $params = "") { // Remember, SSL MUST BE SUPPORTED
        if (is_array($params)) $params = $this->array2url($params);
        $curl = curl_init($url . ($method == "GET" && $params != "" ? "?" . $params : ""));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, ($method == "GET"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, ($method == "POST"));
        if ($method == "POST") curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if (curl_errno($curl) == 0){
            $response;
        }else{
            $this->ErrorStore('OPENID_CURL', curl_error($curl));
        }
        return $response;
}
```

So.. How to translate such function to C++ (using libCURL) from PHP?

Comment: Ofcourse I would love to see full translaion of some php openID library! For example like 600 lines of PHP code (one class) [lightopenid](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/). But scinse no one has done it for me... ok I can try on my own. Because to use not a small `libopkele` for only openID authentification on my small crossplatform  server just does not seem right for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cURL has a C API: [link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/). You can use this from C++ too.

It shouldn't be difficult to rewrite the function you gave when you use the cURL API.